# Geometry Node: Creating Gear

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to create gear in geometry nodes. I first create 2 concentric circles and remove their alternate edges with delete geometry node. I then extrude each point on the outer circle. The offset for extrusion is calculated as the difference of position of each point from outer and inner circle. However the gear is not rendering correctly. What is the reason?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Star + Fillet Curve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you change delete geometry to "edges and faces" only you will get:

[image]

[image]